# Why tcpdump get nothing when music is playing on my local apache?

Tags: tcpdump

No wireline connects to net for my local pc.
Apache2 was installed and a music was put on /var/www/html/test.ogg.
It can be played with chrome  `127.0.0.1/test.ogg`.
tcpdump was running when playing the music----test.ogg with chrome.

```
sudo tcpdump tcp port 80  -i lo -vv
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

Why the command get nothing except`tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the following:

- Is chrome cache cleared?
- What is the response code in chrome - it should be 200 OK.
- Chrome is making a connection on 127.0.0.1:some_ephemeral_port -- to apache:127.0.0.1:80 - make sure it is 80, not 443!
- Start the capture before opening the file (when did you start the capture)?
- In case nothing helps try, `sudo tcpdump -i any -vv port 80` (if you are sure of the port).
- Try capturing other requests - like the apache home page and see if that works.

Comment: cleared both cache in chrome and /tmp directory,it works fine.